# Heorku Application Open Failure

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy me react app on Heroku. Everything says deployed on Heroku but when I type Heroku open, it says application error and the winddow suggests to do Heroku `--tail`. When I do Heroku `--tail` on command line, I receive the following error:

```
 State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-31T21:02:37.775855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-gorge-48530.herokuapp.com request_id=d9a3fe26-753e-417d-b296-b77f9ea48280 fwd="24.105.211.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-31T21:02:39.965317+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-gorge-48530.herokuapp.com request_id=b767e1b3-d89d-4cf1-b762-aa7ca6b06496 fwd="24.105.211.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-31T21:02:47.963754+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-gorge-48530.herokuapp.com request_id=252ba8b0-1413-4762-8f9e-866f4ce263dc fwd="24.105.211.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-31T21:02:48.946628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-gorge-48530.herokuapp.com request_id=ec439c87-bbdd-4880-a3e9-f93911527f1f fwd="24.105.211.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-31T21:03:34.544211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-gorge-48530.herokuapp.com request_id=0d845c3c-198e-48a0-b8ed-225a89af5af0 fwd="24.105.211.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-31T21:03:36.818111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-gorge-48530.herokuapp.com request_id=d179d8d0-da44-4353-99d3-776cb60fa7a4 fwd="24.105.211.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Not enough information to determine the reason for the crash

Answer (score 0):

The problem usually comes from **Procfile**, make sure your **Procfile** was properly set up

Comment: No not really. I never use a **Procfile** when deploying to Heroku. It's not required for a long time now. I would look somewhere else.